# Bad access when passing a UIImage as a parameter -iOS -Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, exc-bad-access

Title is I believe self descriptive so I will start explaining my code..

This is the code that generates an image..

```
- (UIImage *) convertDataToImage {
    NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"screenshot"];
    return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

if I call this method like this `[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sendEmailWithImage:[self convertDataToImage]];` then everything is fine, beside its speed.. coz I have heaps of methods that need the same image.. so I wanna call `convertImageToImage` method once only..

so I tried..

.h

```
UIImage *image;
```

.m init

```
image = [self convertDataToImage];
```

and lastly

```
[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sendEmailWithImage:image];
```

seems to be like everything should work as it was.. but I am getting a bad access error..

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance..

Update: in my init I tried using the following code

```
CCTexture2D *texture = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];

CCSprite *sp = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
sp.position = ccp(100, 100);
[self addChild:sp];
```

and it is working.. but outside init still not working..
I am autoreleasing texture, does it also release my image?

Comment: Do you use ARC in your project?

Comment: I don't use arc.. I updated my question..

Comment: Then I think you should retain the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't use ARC in your project, you should `retain` the `UIImage` instance returned by `[self convertDataToImage]`:

```
image = [[self convertDataToImage] retain];
```

Comment: Also you should probably look into ARC ;)

Comment: how so? have you measured it? No. Arc is not slower, if anything it's **faster**!

Comment: @LearnCocos2D i just did that.. I wrote a method that creates 2 mutablearrays and does some calculations with them.. with autoreleased cocos2d, took 84ms. manually released took 63ms. and arc enabled cocos2d took 77ms.. so still manually releasing objects is the fastest..

Comment: ohhh btw.. i tested them on my computer using the simulator.. not on the actual device.. might be different on actual device..

Comment: yeah, ignore the simulator, and ignore synthetic tests, they're not actual programs. You will never notice a drop in just 1 fps when using ARC, I can tell you that much. The differences you measured are marginal, the difference between fast enumeration and regular counter for loop with objectAtIndex: is likely going to be more significant.

Comment: I will test them as well on the real device.. I don't think arc will be faster like u claimed.. but still I would much prefer to control the objects that I have created.